# How to show console of hidden (background) task in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, services, console

I am using task scheduler. I am runing many console software on Startup.
The console software works great in the background.
Sometimes I want to see the "CONSOLE" of those software.

Is there any way to see the console/window of background process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

I have decided to write small open-source software for that.

Software that let you connect to any other console program, and control it (see the console, and send commands)

### How is it working?

In the task manager you run using the *remote-console*

```
remote-console --server [port] cmd.exe
```

Then, to see the console you need to connect to it:

```
remote-console --client [ip] [port]
```

You just need to install it oce using npm

```
npm i -g node-remote-console
```

pull requests are welcome :)

https://github.com/AminaG/node-remote-console

Answer (score 3):

If you start your task under specified account, option "Run when user is logged on or not", the task can't interact with desktop at all.

The option "Run only when user is logged on" does the trick, but it shows console always.

My personal solution - run console scripts in [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html) it may start it taskbar status area and may be easily reveal from. Example below starts script in ConEmu in certain directory, waits for script finishes and closes the window.

```
Program:
  c:\tools\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe
Add arguments:
  -basic -StartTSA -dir c:\Sources -cmd cmd.exe /c c:\Sources\Maintain.cmd -cur_console:n
```

Some comments

- `-basic` forces some default ConEmu settings without interaction with user on first start.
- The part after `-cmd` is the command itself: `cmd.exe /c c:\Sources\Maintain.cmd`.
- `-cur_console:n` permits automatic window shutdown if script finishes promptly. Must be last switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can not see the console of some of the task becuase they are programed in such a way that they din't use any printing statement in the code so actually you can get balnk console screen only.so there is no meaning to see the blank console of task.